# Error de autenticación en sugarcrm

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hola tengo un problema en sugarcrm, cuando realizo la autenticación en sugarcrm, este no me redirecciona al admin, ni si quiera me muestra un error, la pantalla se queda todo en blanco. 
En el sugarcrm.log tengo este error

> [FATAL] FAILED LOGIN:attempts[1] - admin

He revisando las funciones del login en el php, pero no veo error alguno.
Es como que el error esta en el redireccionamiento, pero no encuentro como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciono sacando de servicio el archivo mvc_utils.php ya que contenía código ofuscado base64, cuando en el servidor estaba desactivado esa función.
Saludos